# All rows from table 1 and matching rows on table 2

Tags: sql, join, teradata

The first part of the code below gives me the correct amount and number of records (776).  When I join to table b, the code runs but doesn't provide the answer I’m looking for.  The problem is that the 2nd table does not contain all of the Department / Account combinations that I’m getting from the first query.

What I’m trying to do is display ALL of the records from the first table regardless if there is a match or not in the second table.  If the combination is in table 2, then I will get an amount.  I tried to using different joins(left, left outer, right, and right outer) without any luck.  All of the joins give me the same number of records (412) instead of 776 because it is matching on Branch.

How can I change this to get all of the records from the first part of the query regardless if there are records on table 2.  Thanks again for all of your help...

```
SELECT
    a.Account,
    a.Branch,
    a.Department,
    a.Amount,
    b.Total_Amount, 
    a.Amount - b.Total_Amount as DIFF

FROM 

    (SELECT 
        pdr.account_fa AS Account,
        ir.branch_lgcy_cd AS Branch,
        pdr.Department,
        sum(pdr.COST) AS Amount

    FROM PSFS.DEPR_RPT pdr 

    INNER JOIN INTGRT_RPT.DIM_LOCATION ir ON pdr.Department = ir._branch_ps_org_cd AND ir.curr_lrd_row_flg = 1

    WHERE pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'A5'
    AND pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = 2015
    AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 8

    GROUP BY Account, Branch, department

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
    pdr.account_ad AS Account,
    ir.erac_branch_lgcy_cd AS Branch,
    pdr.Department,
    sum(pdr.depr_ltd) AS Amount

    FROM PSFS.PS_DEPR_RPT pdr 

    LEFT JOIN INTGRT_RPT.DIM_LOCATION ir ON pdr.Department = ir.branch_ps_org_cd AND ir.curr_lrd_row_flg = 1

    WHERE pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'A5'
    AND pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = 2015
    AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 8

    GROUP BY Account, Branch, Department ) a

INNER JOIN PSFS.PS_GL_ACCT_LDGR b ON a.deptid = b.grp_br_ps_org_id 
    AND a.fa_acct = b.acct_nbr
    AND b.fiscal_yr_mth_nbr = 201508

GROUP BY Account, Branch, Department, Amount, Total_Amount

ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Hi, try using Full outer JOIN

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` should do what you want. It returns all the rows in the first table. If a row doesn't have a match in the second table, it returns `NULL` for those column.

Comment: Can you show some sample input, and the desired output, and make a sqlfiddle to play with ?

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN PSFS.PS_GL_ACCT_LDGR b ON a.deptid` change this to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`